# How to package in html into single application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can I create a single iconic file of several html files like creating .exe file in java using servlets, java beans, dao etc.. please do suggest.

Comment: Java is not javascript. Besides, you should have shown us what you've attemped so far.

Comment: I know that java is not javascript.. I have mentioned the above as an example. I need to package several html5 files into single file which acts as an application. (like .exe)

Comment: Then why did you put javascript as a tag. In this way no java users will see this question, because you either misunderstood what is the difference between java and javascript or you didn't pay enough attention when opening the question. In any case, recommendations in stackoverflow are usually considered off topic. The question is unclear, because we have literally no idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: If you use Phonegap you can package html5 files and it run in a browser, as WebView

Comment: My code is not at all related to java. I am just mentioning u an example by taking java. I am actually working on a project which is related to javascript and html5 , and this question is to fulfill a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tools out there that can embed all the external resources of an html file into a single html file, but not like an .exe file.

Examples:

- https://github.com/remy/inliner
- https://github.com/jgallen23/grunt-inline-css
- https://github.com/ceee/grunt-datauri

Comment: Is there any possibility to do the same with out using any tools??

Comment: Not easily! You'd have to convert all your images and media data to base64 and embed it yourself, and write your own parser to load them back again.

Comment: Hello @priyanka, did you have any luck with this, or could you expand on this requirement you are trying to fulfill?

Comment: @Dreakes sorry i didn't get you.